# can't wrap any custom html around nivo slider title text

Tags: 7, views, javascript

As the nivo module makes this content type called 'slide', there is a title to be set and with views you can normally influence this title field adding some html to it to give it some specific css. But somehow this html doens't get wrapped around the text from the title field.
I made this view called 'slideshow' which is displayed as a block.

**FORMAT:**
Format: views nivo slider
Show: views nivo slider

**FIELDS:**
Content: title

- Unchecked: Create a label, Exclude from display, Link this field to the original piece of conent.
- Style settings: Only checked 'customize field HTML'. Then, from the pull-down list, I set HTML element to STRONG just for testing. No css class yet only wanted to see if there would be strong tags in my nodetitle when inspecting element.

Everything else in Content: title is set to default.

Content: Body - pretty much default. 
Content: Slide - Settings don't really matter. The rest of the block containing this view works rather fine.

**FILTER CRITERIA:**
sorted by date. Doesn't really matter.

Everthing else is pretty much set to default and I don't think it's really relevant for this issue if I'm not mistaken.

So to see what's going on, I would go to a page that shows the block containing this view and rightclick on my nodetitle in the nivo slider caption and inspect element. Only to see that any text that is wrapped in the nivo divs is to be found in a p element with no attributes at all. So leave alone a strong element or whatever I would've chosen under content:title settings in my slideshow view.

Comment: Are you sure the field you're setting output options for is the one you believe ? You can check this by paying attention to the URL Views and Drupal admin section use to edit the fields in the different contexts (names are something like 'field_my_field' in Views) and it should match the content type's field names.

Comment: Well if you want to edit the HTML for the title field in a view in drupal 7 you get an overlay, so you're not going to a URL that has the name of the field you're editing in it instead just /admin/structure/views/view/slideshow/edit. Other than that, yes I'm very sure it's the actual title of my nivo slider content type I'm trying to edit. If it wouldn't be the title to that slideshow, all the other fields that I edited wouldn't apply either but they do apply.

Comment: OK, just wanted to check this. By the way, hust hovering on links will give you the URL at the bottom of the screen in Firefox, and anywhere else on other browsers. As for your problem, you may try to edit the template directly, especially if you have a lot of customization to do. The problem may be in the Nivo module itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by editing the template directly? CSS or another configuration of some sort?

Comment: No, I'm speaking of creating a file in your template directory which will overwrite the standard output of Views. YOu can know what file to create by going to 'Theme information' in your view edit screen. Here is a starting page to learn to do that : http://drupal.org/node/457740.

Comment: Thanks I was just trying to expore this apart from this issue trying to understand it. Could be a solution. I'll try to get my head around this a little quicker.